# Are mushrooms with interior holes ok?

Tags: food-safety, mushrooms

When I started to cut up these store bought mushrooms, I saw there were holes in them. There weren't any holes or spots visible on the exterior. Are they still safe to eat? They also started to turn a bit pink after cutting, maybe some oxidation but it seems unusual.

I buy these all the time and I've never seen these kind of holes in them.

[image: mushrooms with holes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those holes are most likely [caused by some kind of larva](https://nrcmushroom.org/FAQ-Pest_and_Diseases.pdf)(pdf), such as mushroom maggots.

While disgusting, such larva are harmless to humans, and the holes they leave behind are equally harmless. Since you just seem to have the holes, I wouldn't worry about it.